# VB.NET: Can't load Excel into WebBrowser on Windows Form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, excel

I am using the following code to load an Excel sheet into a WebBrowser control on a Windows Form, and the msgbox in the Navigated fires, but the sheet is not visible in the WebBrowser.  Also, Navigated2 does not help.  Is there something that's missing?

FYI: the following references to the project are being declared:

```
Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library
Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library
Microsoft Internet Controls
Microsoft Common Dialog Control 6.0 (SP6)
```

---

```
Imports Office = Microsoft.Office.Core
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class Form1
    Dim oDocument As Object
    Private xlAPP As New Excel.Application
    Private xlWBook As Excel.Workbook

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ' Create new Application.

        Dim filename As String = Nothing
        With OpenFileDialog1
            .CheckFileExists = True
            .ShowReadOnly = True
            .Filter = "Excel files *.xlsx|*.xlsx"
            If .ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                'Load file
                filename = .FileName
            End If
        End With

        With xlAPP
            .Visible = False
            xlWBook = .Workbooks.Open(filename)
            xlWBook.Activate()

        End With

        Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate(xlWBook.FullName)

    End Sub

    Private Sub WebBrowser1_Navigated(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Object) Handles WebBrowser1.Navigated
        MsgBox("NavigateComplete Event")
        On Error Resume Next
        oDocument = pDisp.Document

    End Sub
    Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

        With xlAPP.CommandBars("Standard")
            .Visible = True

        End With
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Did you managed to sort this out? I am having similar issue

Comment: No, decided to populate a DataGridView instead. The original intent was to make Excel part of the code where users can see and edit data.  The webbrowser option with Excel seemed to be like a hornets' nest -- so it was avoided.